# usermod returns "group 'thegroupname' does not exist" for known group

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo, user-groups

As a member of sudo can I add myself to a group I don't belong to?

```
$ getent group thegroupname 
thegroupname:x:123794798:administrator,users,auser,moreusers,manymoreusers

$ sudo usermod -a -G thegroupname myusername
usermod: group 'thegroupname' does not exist
```

When I run the above I can't add myself to the group. The error message says the group doesn't exist, but it does.

Here I'll make a new group as per @terdon's comment.

```
$ sudo groupadd testgroup
useradd: user 'myusername' already exists
$ groups
myusername sudo users

$ getent group testgroup
testgroup:x:01234:


$ sudo usermod -a -G testgroup myusername
$ groups myusername
myusername : myusername sudo users testgroup
```

Sorry for the typo with just using `groups` instead of `groups myusername`. I'm not sure if that information is helpful as it still shows me as not belonging to the test group while `groups myusername` does.

```
$ groups
myusername sudo users
```

Comment: I suppose that creating a new group and adding your user to it does work as expected right? It's only `thisgroupname` that fails?

Comment: @terdon I'm not sure. I could use `usermod` but not `groupadd`. I've updated the question based on your feedback.

Comment: @terdon reading that again, it seems the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Hmm. Strange. Could you fix the typo you where `groupadd` prints a `useradd` error message (2nd code line in your edit)?

Comment: @terdon Doh, I overlooked something obvious trying to add a local account to an Active Directory group. If you want to post that in an answer, feel free! Thanks for your troubleshooting.

Comment: Huh? You mean the issue was thta you were running `sudo useradd testgroup` instead of `groupadd`? If so, lol, and nah, not worth posting an answer, just delete it. It's unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: @terdon No, I forgot the group belonged to Active Directory and that the account I was trying to add it to was a local only account (not a user on AD). I guess the question should be can I add a local account to an AD group...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to add a local user to an Active Directory group. This is not allowed.